# Temporizador en ejecucion c++

Tags: c

0

estoy intentando realizar un temporizador para un ARM, que esta en continua ejecucion, por lo que he optado por utilizar la libreria time.h para evitar bloqueos. Pero al poner el codigo no me hace ninguna accion. Se que sera una chorrada y pido disculpas de antemano, pero estoy con la cabeza bloqueada y por eso pido ayuda por aqui.

El codigo utilizado es este.

```
#include "time.h"

extern int GPIOB_Status;

void temporizador(time_t temp_duracion){
time_t tiempoahora;
tiempoahora= time(NULL);
    if(tiempoahora > tiempoahora + temp_duracion){
    tiempoahora=time(NULL);
        GPIOB_Status &= 0x0000;
          GPIO_SET_OUT_DATA(PB, GPIOB_Status); //PB6/PB5=0              

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ese código no va a funcionar nunca:

```
tiempoahora > tiempoahora + temp_duracion
```

Esa condición **siempre** será falsa: estas comprobando que una variable sea mayor que esa misma variable + un valor. Ni aunque `temp_duracion = 0` se cumplirá la condición.

Además, haces `tiempoahora = time(NULL);` en la función, que no ayuda demasiado a lo que pretendes. Cada vez que llames a esa función, tu variable tomará un nuevo valor, sobre-escribiendo el anterior.

Para esto último, no tienes mas que declarar tu variable como `static`, con lo que el valor será *persistente* entre llamadas:

```
static time_t tiempoahora = time( NULL );
```

Y arreglar la condición de tu bucle, añadiendo una nueva variable:

```
void temporizador( time_t temp_duracion ) {
  static time_t tiempoAnterior = 0;

  time_t tiempoAhora = time( NULL );

  if( tiempoaAhora > ( tiempoAnterior + temp_duracion ) ) {
    tiempoAnterior = tiempoAhora;
    GPIOB_Status &= 0x0000;
    GPIO_SET_OUT_DATA( PB, GPIOB_Status );
  }
}
```

Comment: He intentado lo que me as puesto, y si a sido un despiste pero llevo unos dias que no me concentro, el tema he puesto tu codigo pero en cuanto llamo a la funcion me ejecuta el temporizador sin mas, es como que siempre es cierta la condicion.

Nunca pense que un temporizador tonto me daria tantos dolores de cabeza